# Strange work of Oracle index

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

I'm added bitmap index to an existing table

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX idx_1 ON table1 (col1) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

But when I explain plan of the query, the new index is not used by optimizer and table full scanned.

After that I created a copy of my table and created the same index and index is used by optimizer!

I dropped and recreated index on both original and copy tables but the result is same - on original table index is not working while on copy table index is working.

When I try to hint optimizer to use an index on the original table the cost is 3 times higher than full table scan approach.

I'm using Oracle 11gr2.

```
    create table AP_IT.T_LEAD_MAIN3
(
  id                NUMBER not null,
  fill_date         DATE not null,
  source_code       NUMBER default 0 not null,
  product_code      NUMBER not null,
  phone             VARCHAR2(64) not null,
  amount            NUMBER,
  amount_scored     NUMBER,
  birthdate         DATE,
  children          NUMBER,
  city_name         VARCHAR2(200),
  city_type         VARCHAR2(4),
  convenient_time   VARCHAR2(400),
  email             VARCHAR2(200),
  firstname         VARCHAR2(200),
  homephone         VARCHAR2(64),
  id_type_form      VARCHAR2(120),
  iin               VARCHAR2(48),
  lastname          VARCHAR2(200),
  marriage          VARCHAR2(4),
  middlename        VARCHAR2(200),
  name              VARCHAR2(600),
  offer_type        VARCHAR2(80),
  order_number      VARCHAR2(120),
  pensioner         VARCHAR2(4),
  period            NUMBER default 0,
  period_scored     NUMBER,
  place_to_get_loan VARCHAR2(400),
  region            VARCHAR2(12),
  rnn               VARCHAR2(48),
  salary            NUMBER,
  score_date        DATE,
  scored            NUMBER default 0,
  sent_email        DATE,
  sent_sms          DATE,
  sex               VARCHAR2(4),
  udost             VARCHAR2(36),
  udost_enddate     DATE,
  work_date         DATE,
  id_old            NUMBER(32),
  transac_type      NUMBER,
  utm_test          NVARCHAR2(100),
  utm_content       NVARCHAR2(100),
  utm_medium        NVARCHAR2(100),
  utm_name          NVARCHAR2(100),
  utm_source        NVARCHAR2(100),
  utm_term          NVARCHAR2(100),
  order_id          NUMBER,
  mm                NUMBER,
  call_start_time   VARCHAR2(10),
  call_end_time     VARCHAR2(10),
  call_date         DATE
)
tablespace RISK_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 80K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );

-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table AP_IT.T_LEAD_MAIN3
  add constraint PK_LEAD_MAIN3 primary key (ID)
  using index 
  tablespace RISK_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 80K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
alter table AP_IT.T_LEAD_MAIN3
  add foreign key (SOURCE_CODE)
  references AP_IT.T_LEAD_SOURCE (SOURCE_CODE);
alter table AP_IT.T_LEAD_MAIN3
  add foreign key (PRODUCT_CODE)
  references AP_IT.T_LEAD_PRODUCT (PRODUCT_CODE);

CREATE BITMAP INDEX idx_tblleadmain_3
ON AP_IT.T_LEAD_MAIN3 (SCORED) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

The query:

```
select "AMOUNT_SCORED","ORDER_NUMBER","SCORED" 
from ap_it.t_lead_main3 t 
where t.scored = 1
```

Plan for original table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)|
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |   573K|  4284   (1)|
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_LEAD_MAIN |   573K|  4284   (1)|
--------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("T"."SCORED"=1)
```

Plan for copy table

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2628593030
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name              | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                   |   753K|  1637   (1)|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T_LEAD_MAIN3      |   753K|  1637   (1)|
|   2 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS|                   |       |            |
|*  3 |    BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE | IDX_TBLLEADMAIN_3 |       |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - access("T"."SCORED"=1)
```

Comment: table schema? query text?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: `select * from schema1.table1 t where t.col1 = 1`

Comment: Please show execution plans of both queries. Usually a single BITMAP index is useless, typically you combine several of them with "AND". [COMPUTE STATISTICS Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_1008.htm#sthref3938): *This clause has been deprecated. Oracle Database now automatically collects statistics during index creation and rebuild. This clause is supported for backward compatibility and will not cause errors.*, i.e you should skip `COMPUTE STATISTICS`

Comment: Why did you leave out the `COST`, `E-Rows` and `E-Bytes` columns from the plans? They are vital in understanding why Oracle chooses one plan over the other?

Comment: Did you run `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats()` on the original table after creating the index?

Comment: sorry, edited the question. No i didnt use 'dbms_stats.gather_table_stats()'

Comment: It might just be that a full table scan is less expensive than an index scan (this is how the CBO works). In your case I think its just that you haven't gather table statistics on the original table, which resulted in different execution plan on both, even though they have the same data + the same indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered the question:

> After that I created a copy of my table and created the same index ...

Creating a copy of a table (using `CTAS` - create table .. as select ..) produces not an identical clone of the original table, but both the *space allocation* (e.g. if the original table consist of lot of free space after deletes) and *order or rows* (e.g. creating with `order by`) may change.

So for the original table the `CBO` calculates lower cost for `FULL TABLE SCAN` but for the new table (after your *reorganisation* with CTAS) the bit map indexx access is prefered.

The whole truth can only be obtained if you trace both your queries with the [10053 trace](http://www.centrexcc.com/A%20Look%20under%20the%20Hood%20of%20CBO%20-%20the%2010053%20Event.pdf) but as a rule you **should not expect the same optimizer behavior for same (logical) data. The physical layout of the table plays a crutial role**.

Comment: Ok, I didn't use order by clause in ctas but I understood your explanation. There is another question, can gathering statistics on table can help me?

Comment: By "help me" I assume that you want to force the database to use the index and yes that may work.However, another explanation is that Oracle is doing the right thing and that a full scan is faster than using the index.

Comment: Tried to gather statistics on copy table for fun and index is not used by optimizer also(

Comment: @akaipbay well, yes, statistics are very relevant for the CBO. Check [`dynamic sampling`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#PFGRF30101), which is what happens when optimizer statistics are missing